# Is there any way to save data enlisted in the Browser WebDeveloper tool>>Application>>Cookies section?

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-devtools, web-developer-toolbar

There are several data present in the Cookies section of "Application Tab" in Chrome Web developer tool. How can we save them in a file like excel, notepad,etc ?

Comment: Find an extension that exports them. Or write your own. Chrome doesn't have the cookie export feature.

Comment: you tagged this as both firefox and chrome, why? the answers are likely different for each browser, so you should ask separate questions if you want both